# CKEDITOR add Styling

Tags: css, ckeditor

I'm trying to set some css to the CKEDITOR 4 programmaticly. 
This because when a new user comes to the editor i would like to identify him with a different color.

Within the registered style array i do see the added row(CKEDITOR.stylesSet.registered.user0). but the style isn't visible in the editor?
Why is this? and what am i doing wrong?

```
setStyling: function(editor)
{
    var userIds = this.getUserIds(editor);// returns an array with id's
    var colors = editor.config.Colors;    // Colors are set in the config

    for(var i = 0; userIds.length > i; i++)
    {
        if(CKEDITOR.stylesSet.get('user' + i) === null)
        {
            CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('user' + i, [
                { name: 'userColor', element: 'span[data-uid="' + userIds[i] +'"]', styles: { color: colors[i] }}
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that CKEDITOR.stylesSet.loaded doesn't show my add CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another aproach did the job:

```
    var $head = $("iframe").contents().find("head");
    var $style = $("iframe").contents().find("#uniqueStyle");
    var css = "";

    for(var i = 0; userIds.length > i; i++)
    {
        css += "span[data-uid='" + userIds[i] + "'] { color: " + colors[i] + "; } ";
    }

    if($style)
    {
        $style.remove();
    }

    $('<style id="uniqueStyle" type="text/css"></style>')
        .html(css)
        .appendTo($head);
```